# Send ESMTP emails using PHP by direct SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, synology

I have a mail server on a Synology DiskStation. I want to send emails using php but PHP mail function does not work. I have read that Synology mail server uses ESMTP and PHP uses sendmail so the mail function does not work and i need to build my message using direct SMTP. I found this:

```
<?php
function myMail($from, $namefrom, $to, $nameto, $subject, $message) {
$smtpServer = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";   
$port = "25";                    
$timeout = "45";                 // typical timeout. try 45 for slow servers
$username = "user@example.com";
$password = "secret";           
$localhost = "example.com";      
$newLine = "\r\n";
$secure = 0;
$smtpConnect = fsockopen($smtpServer, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 4096);
if(empty($smtpConnect)) {
   $output = "Failed to connect: $smtpResponse";
   echo $output;
   return $output;
}
else {
   $logArray['connection'] = "<p>Connected to: $smtpResponse";
   echo "<p />connection accepted<br>".$smtpResponse."<p />Continuing<p />";
}
fputs($smtpConnect, "HELO $localhost". $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 4096);
$logArray['heloresponse2'] = "$smtpResponse";
fputs($smtpConnect,"AUTH LOGIN" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 4096);
$logArray['authrequest'] = "$smtpResponse";
fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($username) . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 4096);
$logArray['authusername'] = "$smtpResponse";
fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($password) . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 4096);
$logArray['authpassword'] = "$smtpResponse";
fputs($smtpConnect, "MAIL FROM: <$from>" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 4096);
$logArray['mailfromresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";
fputs($smtpConnect, "RCPT TO: <$to>" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 4096);
$logArray['mailtoresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";
fputs($smtpConnect, "DATA" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 4096);
$logArray['data1response'] = "$smtpResponse";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $newLine;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . $newLine;
$headers .= "To: $nameto <$to>" . $newLine;
$headers .= "From: $namefrom <$from>" . $newLine;
fputs($smtpConnect, "To: $to\r\nFrom: $from\r\nSubject: $subject\r\n$headers\r\n\r\n$message\r\n.\r\n");
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 4096);
$logArray['data2response'] = "$smtpResponse";

fputs($smtpConnect,"QUIT" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 4096);
$logArray['quitresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";
$logArray['quitcode'] = substr($smtpResponse,0,3);
fclose($smtpConnect);
//a return value of 221 in $retVal["quitcode"] is a success
return($logArray);
}
```

And it returns:
*connection accepted
220 example.com ESMTP Postfix*

Continuing
But my email does not arrive.
Thank you for help.

NOTE: Hostname was replaced by example.com

Comment: If the ESMTP server accepted it, your code is fine. I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions, not email deliverability questions. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam

Comment: @tripleee Do what you want, I asked this question ages ago when I was a young kid:D (I no longer use PHP and this was some copied piece of code) It is arguably not the best question, however, I still think it is related to programming and back then I didn't understand what does this output mean (you say the code is okay but I didn't know that). So in general I think this question theoretically could be useful but I understand it may not reach quite the quality level for SO. Today I don't really remember any details related to this question.

Comment: Would it not make sense to delete it then? It's probably a duplicate anyhow.